# http streaming with gst-launch (GStreamer)

Tags: linux, gstreamer

How do I do http streaming with GStreamer?

Yes, I googled it and couldn't find an answer to this simple question anywhere.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What were your results?  What are you trying to stream?

Comment: I want to stream from a webcam. However, I can't find any destination "sink" for http-streaming (only for RSTP via UDP). As a possible workaround, I could dump the output to stdout and use vlc with the "-" parameter (= read from stdin), but I wondered there was a way to do http streaming from gst directly.

Answer (score 14):

I think you can use new `hlssink` plugin

Simple pipe to test `hlssink` localy:
`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink max-files=5`
then run vlc:
`cvlc playlist.m3u8`

if you want stream via net, start you web server and correct pipe:
        `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink max-files=5  playlist-root=http://server.com location=/var/www/hlssink playlist-location=/var/www/hlssink`
there
`/var/www/hlssink` is your `document_root` directory
and open `http://server.com/playlist.m3u8` playlist in `vlc`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the tcpserversink element from the tcp plugin:
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-tcpserversink.html

Comment: Could you please describe how does it apply to the question? (Plain TCP versus HTTP)